# View can't find layout page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

My view can't find layout. But everything looks fine. My structure is shown below:

[image]

And my view is shown below:

```
@model xxx.Web.Model.Home.IndexModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/_MainLayout.cshtml";
}
```

And my layout is shown below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="tr">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Bootstrappage:Free Bootstrap Template (bootstrap 2.3.1 version)</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">
<!-- 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/style/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/style/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" />
-->
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="../../themes/less/bootstrap.less">
<script src="../../themes/js/less/less.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="assets/ico/favicon.ico">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="144x144" href="assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-144-precomposed.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="114x114" href="assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-114-precomposed.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="72x72" href="assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-72-precomposed.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-57-precomposed.png">
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        @RenderSection("DocumentReady", false)
    });
</script>
</head>
<body data-offset="40">
@{Html.RenderAction("Header", "Partial");}
@{Html.RenderAction("Navbar", "Partial");}
@RenderBody()
@{Html.RenderAction("Footer", "Partial");}
<script src="themes/js/lib/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Also my controller is shown below:

```
 public ActionResult Index()
    {
        IndexModel model = new IndexModel();
        HomeModelFactory modelFactory = new HomeModelFactory();
        model.Files = modelFactory.CreateIndexModel();

        return View(model);
    }
```

And exception:
[image]

Why I am getting this exception? It was working well.

Comment: Something has obviously changed recently for it to suddenly stop working.  Are you able to compare to a version that was working?

Comment: Only I added "@model xxx.Web.Model.Home.IndexModel" in top of the cshtml.

Comment: Can you please show us the contents of _MainLayout.cshtml? I suspect there is a variable you're trying to use which is null

Comment: Why the need to move away from the conventions? eg `\Views\_ViewStart.cshtml` and `\Views\Shared\_Layout.cshtml`.  The reason I ask is because ASP.NET MVC has always been about Convention over Configuration to avoid these types of issues.

Comment: Question updated. Added _MainLayout.cshtml content.

Comment: move _MainLayout.cshtml inside shared folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And the full contents of the View / Controller as well please?

Some possible scenarios without looking at the View / Controller are;
- Some sections are missing (e.g. "DocumentReady")
- The view is trying to resolve model properties which are not set (i.e null)

Comment: Guys i found the problem. My model is always null so i'am getting exception. It is not about Layout page.

Comment: That's great. If the model being null is part of the business logic, you may want to add a null check in the view and show an error (either generic or specific) to the user rather than risking a null reference exception at client side.

Comment: @fuat - same problem was with me. But error was pointing out to layout page, like layout has some null reference.

Answer (score 0):

You might check your properties setting on your _MainLayout.cshtml file. I had this same problem (the Layout page could not be found in the search path) until I set the VisualStudio properties BuildAction to Content. I had copied the file and renamed it, and the property had been set to 'none'.

Answer (score -4):

This is your problem: `Layout = "~/Views/_MainLayout.cshtml";`

The _Layout reference should be `Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_MainLayout.cshtml";`

Dont make these type of mistakes again!

Comment: It is not correct. Layout view can be anywhere. Also tried Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_MainLayout.cshtml";. Still same.

Comment: The `_MainLayout.cshtml` file isn't in the `/shared` directory.  Take a closer look at the directory screen shot

Comment: This is misleading. I am having the same problem, answer like this doesn't help.